# php.ini changes not taking effect in Siteground

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting, magento, phpmyadmin

I am importing an sql file for a magento website, however, It gives me this error:

```
Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change   
max_input_vars in php.ini
```

Then I modified the max_input_vars to 3000 in the php.ini but it doesn't seem to take effect.
I'm pretty new at this and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Presumably you restarted Apache/PHP after making the change to php.ini? What version of PHP are you running? (Curious why you get this error when "importing an SQL file"?)

Comment: I have not tried restarting the apache yet. Is this what caused the changes to not take effect?

Comment: Yes, Apache will need to be restarted for the changes to php.ini to take effect (assuming this is the main php.ini file and not a per-directory php.ini file?).

Comment: It's the one in cpanel where I can change the values of variable. Do I need an ssh access to be able to restart apache? Cos I don't see any options in cpanel to restart.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that option in cPanel - is this your own server? However, if cPanel gives you the option then it must "do the necessary" for you I would assume. Incidentally, this setting can also be set in `.htaccess` and `.user.ini` files - you don't _need_ cPanel/php.ini to set this (although whether it can be overridden is another matter).

Comment: I'm currently using their 3.95 plan shared hosting but I'll give those other options a try.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that my sql file got corrupted when exporting from phpmyadmin. Instead, I exported from command line with this command:

```
mysqldump -u [USER] -p [PASS] db-name > db-name.sql
```

Or if it's too large then you can zip it.

```
mysqldump -u [USER] -p [PASS] db-name | gzip > db-name.gz
```